# Custom Auto Slider?

Tags: java, android

I have build one custom slider. which auto slides the image. but the problem is. suppose I have 3 images. so it's sliding like 1st image to 2nd image to 3rd image and then again go back's to 2nd image. but I want like 1st image to 2nd image to 3rd image and then again go back's to 1st image.

```
recyclerViewHeaderSlider.setLayoutManager(new CustomLinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        headerSliderAdapter.setOnClick(this);
        recyclerViewHeaderSlider.setAdapter(headerSliderAdapter);
        final int speedScroll = 6000;
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            int count = 0;
            boolean flag = true;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(count < headerSliderAdapter.getItemCount()){
                    if(count==headerSliderAdapter.getItemCount()-1){
                        flag = false;
                    }else if(count == 0){
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    if(flag) count++;
                    else count--;

                    recyclerViewHeaderSlider.smoothScrollToPosition(count);
                    handler.postDelayed(this,speedScroll);
                }
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable,speedScroll);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your logic like below.

```
final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
schedular.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Message message = handler.obtainMessage();
                handler.sendMessage(message);
            }
        }, 0, 6000, TimeUnit
                .SECONDS);

    }
final Handler  handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            if (count == headerSliderAdapter.getItemCount() - 1) {
                count = 0;
            } else {
                count++;
            }
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(count);
        }
    };
```